# Как с помощью стилей добиться треугольных скосов в блоках?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, изображения

Приветствую! Подскажите плиз, как с помощью стилей добиться таких скосов в блоках как на картинках 1 и 2, причем, чтобы текст мог быть разной высоты - это вообще возможно или с помощью скриптов только?
[image: картинка 1]
[image: картинка 2]

```css
.tech,
.new {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tech">техника</div>
<div class="new">новинки</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот еще один вариант реализации этой задачи с использованием `transform: skew` (у тестовых примеров, фигуры подсвечены красным для ясности):

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.has_right_arr:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: -7px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50%;
    background: #000;

    -ms-transform: skew(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
    transform: skew(45deg);
}
.has_right_arr:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    bottom: 0;
    right: -7px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50%;
    background: #000;

    -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
    transform: skew(-45deg);
}
.has_right_skew:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    bottom: 0;
    right: -7px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;

    -ms-transform: skew(-25deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
    transform: skew(-25deg);
}

.debug:after {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.debug:before {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<span class="item has_right_arr debug">Hello world! Debug</span>
<br/>
<span class="item has_right_skew debug">Hello everyone! Debug</span>
<br />
<span class="item has_right_arr">Hello world!</span>
<br/>
<span class="item has_right_skew">Hello everyone!</span>
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ey4zek1e/

Comment: к сожалению, для разной высоты хрень получается.. http://jsfiddle.net/ey4zek1e/1/

Comment: @Вася, для большей высоты нужно просто провести небольшой тюнинг: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ey4zek1e/2/

Comment: да, вот сейчас- отлично!

Answer (score 3):

Вариант для современных браузеров ( уже задавали подобные вопросы, но там были другие фигуры, поэтому повторюсь)

Используйте `css` свойство `clip-path`. Поддерживает и треугольники, круги, квадраты, ромбы и другие многоульники

[Тут можно поиграться](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

**Из плюсов**

- Очень хорошая кастомизация
- Без доп элементов
- Не так много кода ( с генератором вообще на раз два делается )

**UPD**
Для кроссбраузерности, лучше не парится и нарисовать нужные бэкграунды. В старых браузерах по другому треугольники не сделать

Comment: благодарю! но, мне нужна кроссбраузерность, даже edge `clip-path` не поддерживает..

Comment: Да, автор ответа прав. Для кроссбраузерности - всё же графика (либо SWG/VML, что, скорее, добавит проблем)

Answer (score 2):

Доброго дня!

Треугольник в левом верхнем углу (как фигура для "Техника спецназначения"):

```css
#triangle-topleft {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid red; 
 border-right: 100px solid transparent;   
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
```

Фигура для "Новинки":

```css
#triangle-right {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 40px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid red;
 border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-right"></div>
```

Если немного напрячь разум, можно применить эти трюки к псевдоэлементам и вообще избавиться от дополнительных блоков в HTML.
Добавлю еще: углы регулируются шириной border-ов.

[Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/) взят ответ на Ваш вопрос, там же есть много других полезных фигур на CSS.

P.S.: Все работает при любом размере блоков

```css
.tech,
.new {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.tech::after {
 content: ' ';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 30px solid yellow; /* равен высоте блока */
 border-right: 15px solid transparent; /* регулирует угол скоса */
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
}
.new::after {
content: ' ';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 15px solid transparent; /* половина высоты блока */
 border-left: 15px solid yellow; /* половина высоты блока */
 border-bottom: 15px solid transparent; /* регулирует угол скоса */
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tech">техника</div>
<div class="new">новинки</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но вы попробуйте добиться именно подобных кнопок - все не так просто и очевидно, как кажется на первый взгляд, т.к. угол должен быть не столь заостренный

Comment: вопрос остается открыт

Comment: А Вы совсем не пробовали поэкспериментироваь с примерами? Я же дал наводку - border-width.

Comment: пробовал, но для моей высоты не получается, слишком маленькая, не заостряется у меня угол - вы сами попробуйте  говорю - увидите

Comment: Не вопрос, попробовал. Не понимаю, где и что у Вас могло не получиться. См. исправленный ответ

Comment: спасибо! но, обратите внимание на описание "текст мог быть разной высоты"

Answer (score 1):

```css
.skos {
    height:20px;
    width:120px;
    padding-left:40px;
    background:red;
    line-height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
.skos:after{
    content:'';
    border-bottom:30px solid  transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    right:0; top:0;
}
/********************/
.right{
    width:120px;
    height:20px;
    margin:50px 0;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.right:after{
    content:'';
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-left:10px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    right:-20px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="skos">menu</div>
<div class="right">menu</div>
```

да вроде не сложно это ! так надо ?

Comment: + но попробуйте в 2 строчки сделать

Answer (score 0):

Общими усилиями [решение найдено!](http://jsfiddle.net/SerzN1/bpmqbzsp/)
Спасибо за помощь!

```css
a {
  color: #fefefe;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #666;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  &: after, &: before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
  }
}
.arrow:after {
  top: 50%;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 25px solid #fff;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: '';
  bottom: 50%;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 25px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"><a href='#'>Ссылка со стрелкой</a>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="arrow" style="width:300px;"><a href='#'>Ссылка скошеный край<br/> Ссылка скошеный край</a>
</div>
```